# How to connect to Visual FoxPro database using ngrok

Tags: foxpro, ngrok

We are working on a project where we use ngrok for opening a tunnel to our network to perform operations on the user's machine.As part of this, we have to do open ports of different types of databases.
SQL SERVER default port (1433) is opened correctly using Ngrok. However, we are having issues while opening the port of a file-based database like Visual Foxpro database as we don't know port number.

Can anybody help me, how to find the Visual Foxpro database port number or how to connect  Visual Foxpro database using ngrok?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, including the following:

1. Create a VFP web service using the old MS SOAP Toolkit
2. Create a VFP DLL and wrap it with a .Net web service
3. Use a VFP web framework like ActiveVFP or West-Wind Web Connection to write a web service

Look up some of Rick Strahl's articles for all things pertaining to VFP and the web, including this one:

http://www.codemag.com/Article/0703062/Visual-FoxPro-Web-Services-Revisited

Answer (score 0):

Visual Foxpro's database is purely file-based (unless you're using remote views against SQL Server or something).

As a result there is no port number involved. If the data is in a network location then that location needs to be shared and then you access it via the share.

For example if you need to access it from a Windows application then most people use the Visual FoxPro OLEDB driver.

See also [Is there any way we can connect to document databases like Visual Fox pro using TCP tunneling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180844/how-to-connect-to-visual-foxpro-database-using-ngrok/48184933#48184933)

Answer (score 0):

I have used ColdFusion to create a SOAP endpoint that can query and update a VFP database. It was capable of servicing hundreds of calls per second and was stable. You do it by creating classes in CF that relate to the logical entities (tables) in VFP, and you write methods that perform the SQL query or update against the VFP tables, and return the values.